# I'm trying to format date using angular pipe, but it is not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I'm having trouble displaying date using date pipe in Angular 7.

I've tried formatting it using `date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'`, but that doesn't do anything.

I've also tried leaving it as `date`, but that also doesn't do anything.

It displays like this:

```
Mon Oct 12 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

HTML:

```
{{employee.dateOfBirth | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

.ts:

```
dateOfBirth: Date
dateOfBirth: new Date ('10/12/1992')
```

Not sure what is going on.

I would like the date to be displayed in the following format: `dd/MM/yyyy`

Here is my HTML File:

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.name}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img class="imageClass" [src]="employee.photoPath" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Gender
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.gender}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Date of Birth
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.dateOfBirth | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Email
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.email}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Phone Number
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.phoneNumber}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Contact Preference
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.contactPreference}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Date of Birth
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.dateOfBirth}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Department
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.department}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col1Title">
              Is Active
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.isActive}}
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my .ts File:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './list-employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-employees.component.css']
})
export class ListEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Employee[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Mark',
      gender: 'Male',
      contactPreference: 'Email',
      email: 'emp1@fedex.com',
      dateOfBirth: new Date ('10/12/1992'),
      department: 'IT',
      isActive: true,
      photoPath: 'assets/images/emp1.png'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Marty',
      gender: 'Male',
      contactPreference: 'Phone',
      phoneNumber: 7871234452,
      email: 'emp2@fedex.com',
      dateOfBirth: new Date ('05/13/1987'),
      department: 'HR',
      isActive: true,
      photoPath: 'assets/images/emp2.png'
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: 'John',
    gender: 'Male',
    contactPreference: 'Phone',
    phoneNumber: 7870123421,
    email: 'emp3@fedex.com',
    dateOfBirth: new Date('02/22/1990'),
    department: 'IT',
    isActive: true,
    photoPath: 'assets/images/emp3.png'
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
Even with {{employee.dateOfBirth | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}
the date displays as Mon Oct 12 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Comment: `{{dateObj | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`  this is working for me even if its Date object or dateString. Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-formating?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Can you share a repro sample

Comment: I believe you meant `dateOfBirth = new Date('10/12/1992')`. equal. not colon.

Comment: In typescript the colon is used instead of the equal sign. And I've tried formatting like that for the date object and still does nothing. I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're assigning the value to 'dateOfBirth' is not right.
You should assign it like this

```
dateOfBirth: Date = new Date ('10/12/1992');
```

Or you can assign the value in ngOnInit method if you want it to be dynamic.
In your template it should look like this.

```
{{dateOfBirth | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Here is a working StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqmbzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: For some reason this {{dateOfBirth | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} does not work for me. Were any changes made in the lates version of Angular? I'm using Angular 7.1.4.

Comment: I'm using 7.2.3, and it works fine in my project. I don't think there are any changes. It's still mentioned in the official documentation. What's the error you're facing?

Comment: I've updated my StackBlitz with your code. and it seems to work fine. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqmbzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html